# Bad archive mirror

Tags: system-installation, interface, unetbootin, puppetmaster

I have a puppet server to install Ubuntu on devices using net boot.

When connecting a laptop via Ethernet it is booting from the puppet server but when reach the network configuration it shows an error that the network interface is not available and when skipping this warning I got the below picture:

[image]

When I try to boot on another laptop and VMs the worked fine correctly, which means that the puppet server configuration is fine and the problem caused by the Laptop NIC but how could the laptop boot the boot loader if the NIC has an issue, any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by updating ubuntu img, as per the problem caused by the ethernet driver on the laptop.